# Inset disappears once PlotLegends is moved

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, legending, inset

The following code shows three positions for placing the `PlotLegends`. Weirdly, only in the first case can we see the `Inset` 'MyLabel' (working in MMA Version 13.1). How to make the `Inset` visible in the latter cases?

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, 2.9, 2.8, 1.9, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 
     2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7, 2.3}, {2.4, 
     1.0, 2.6, 2.4, 1.0, 2.6, 2.4}}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, #], 
   Epilog -> Inset["MyLabel", Scaled[{0.9, 0.1}]], 
   ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {Before, {Right, 
   Center}, {{0.1, 0.6}, {0, 0}}}
```

[image]

Comment: `Inset[Style["MyLabel", 
  15], Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic]`.

Comment: @cvgmt Those do not produce what `Scaled[{0.9, 0.1}]` actually specifies, even in your first comment.

Comment: @cvgmt I don't understand. I want to control where the inset is placed by `Scaled[{0.9, 0.1}]`. Anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{.9,.1}` work.

```
ListLinePlot3D[{{2.1, 2.9, 2.8, 1.9, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1}, {2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 
     2.2, 2.7, 1.1, 2.2}, {2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7, 2.3, 1.7, 2.3}, {2.4, 
     1.0, 2.6, 2.4, 1.0, 2.6, 2.4}}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, #], 
   Epilog -> Inset["MyLabel", {.9, .1}, Automatic, Automatic], 
   ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {Before, {Right, 
   Center}, {{0.1, 0.6}, {0, 0}}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Replace `Scaled[{0.9, 0.1}]` with `ImageScaled[{0.9, 0.1}]` (or with `{.9, .1}` as in cvgmt's answer)  to get

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This now makes more sense as it's not very clear to me how `{0.9,0.1}` could work (maybe undocumented). Do you think it is a bug that `Scaled` does not work?